# How do I implement the datetime module into my code?

Tags: python, oop

```
from datetime import datetime

class User:
    def __init__(self, username, mail, date_of_birth, gender, password):
        self.username = username
        self.mail = mail
        self.date_of_birth = datetime.date(date_of_birth)
        self.gender = gender
        self.password = password

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.mail

    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self.date_of_birth
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender

    def get_password(self):
        self.password



Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", 21.12.1999 , "Password987")
```

So how do I make the string a date?

The error:

```
Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", 21.12.1999 , "Password987")
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: it sounds like you want to parse a string into a datetime object.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", 21.12.1999 , "Password987")
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What you've typed is not a string. You'll have to enclose it in quotes first of all - i.e. `"21.12.1999"` - `User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999", "Password987")` - and then you can split it inside your function and create a date from it. `strptime` allows you to convert an arbitrary format into a date object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating your object you have to enclose the value inside quotes:

```
User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999", "Password987")
```

Just `21.12.1999` by itself isn't a valid Python definition of anything.

You can then use `strptime` of the `datetime.datetime` module to parse it into a datetime, and retrieve the date from that value:

```
self.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
```

The `%d` corresponds to the day, the `%m` the month and `%Y` to the year in the string being sent in. Calling `date()` on the datetime drops the time-part and returns a pure date instead.

Comment: You wrote datetime.datetime.strptime, do you mean datetime.strptime?

Comment: And what does the .date() do?

Comment: @loky No, `strptime` lives under the `datetime` module inside `datetime`. Unless you import datetime.datetime as datetime, using two levels of `datetime` is the correct path. i.e. `import datetime` still requires you to reference `datetime` beneath `datetime` (it's confusing, I know). `date()` returns the `datetime` object as a `date` object instead, dropping the time part (as mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with :

```
Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", 21.12.1999 , "Password987")
```

- The init function is expecting to have 5 arguments while you pass only 4.
- `21.12.1999` is undefined. You need to pass it as string or Date object